# ReactJS materialize select only renders after refresh

Tags: jquery, reactjs, materialize

I'm creating a react.js app with materialize, but when i'm trying to put in a select, it doesn't render until I refresh the page.

**Index.html (shortened)**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(() => {
         $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
         $("select").material_select();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The select isn't on the homepage and I guess after the redirect the document.ready function doesn't get called again until i reload?

Comment: As much as possible, try to avoid react with other libraries until you dont have a way. We already have react-materialize module which gives all the features of materialized way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing native select element write a wrapped select element may be using HOC and call the jQuery method on that select method in component did mount